# PHP: splitting the date and time within a timestamp value in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I have a field called "timestamp" in a database table which stores value in this format :- YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.

I would like to split apart and then fetch the date (YYYY-MM-DD) in a variable and also the time (HH:MM:SS) in another variable. Example:

```
$timestamp = "2012-10-19 18:19:56";
$get_date = "2012-10-19";
$get_time = "18:19:56";
```

I would be glad if anyone can help out with this using php.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could simply split the string by the space character using PHP's [`explode()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) -

```
$timestamp = "2012-10-19 18:19:56";
$splitTimeStamp = explode(" ",$timestamp);
$date = $splitTimeStamp[0];
$time = $splitTimeStamp[1];
```

Another way of doing this would be this would be to use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) combined with [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)-

```
$date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($timestamp));
$time = date('H:i:s',strtotime($timestamp));
```

Answer (score 3):

Thats simple, use explode, try this below it wil work

```
$new_time = explode(" ",$timestamp);
$get_date = $new_time[0];
$get_time = $new_time[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function; plus [`list`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) function could make your code slightly shorter:

```
list($get_date, $get_time) = explode(" ", "2012-10-19 18:19:56");
var_dump($get_date, $get_time);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$timestamp = "2012-10-19 18:19:56";

$splits =  explode(" ",$timestamp);

$get_date = $splits[0];

$get_time = $splits[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

If your timestamp format is "1 Jan 2018 15:00:01", with explode() the date will only return as '1. With DateTime is the perfect solution.

```
$timestamp = new DateTime("2011-08-04 15:00:01");
$date = $timestamp->format('Y-m-d');
$time = $timestamp->format('H:i:s');
```

Comment: Hi @8cent nice solution using `DateTime` please try and provide more than just code as an answer, try and answer the question of why you have posted this answer, why it is a worthwhile solution.

Comment: if your timestamp is  format as 1 Jan 2018 15:00:01, with `explode()` the date will only return as '1' only. 
With `DateTime` is the perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

instead of exploding you can simply do it like this. This will help you for what ever format you have.

```
echo $timestamp = "2012-10-19 18:19:56";
echo '<br>';
echo $data = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($timestamp));
echo '<br>';
echo $time = date('H:i:s',strtotime($timestamp));
```

Out put

```
2012-10-19 18:19:56
2012-10-19
18:19:56
```

Answer (score -1):

check this PHP fiddle:

http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php\n\n$datetime%20=%20%2228-1-2011%2014:32:55%22;\nlist($date,%20$time)=explode(%27%20%27,%20$datetime);\n\n//%20check%20the%20result\necho%20%22date:%22.%20$date;\necho%20%22%3Cbr%3Etime:%22.%20$time;\n\n//%20further%20more%20you%20can%20easily%20split%20the%20date%20into\n//%20year%20month%20and%20day\nlist($year,%20$month,%20$day)=explode(%27-%27,%20$date);\n\n?%3E\n

Comment: Please consider adding some text about what you did in the fiddle, also make sure that your link is displaying correctly, because this link is broken