# How to insert strings into displayed timestamp?

Tags: php, sql, timestamp, smarty

**SITUATION**:

I am building a support ticket system where the employee can respond to a ticket. This gets displayed within a sort've chat display, which also includes the time the post was made at.

The date gets stored within a database, and gets saved as a timestamp.

I currently am wondering how I can inject strings inside the retrieved timestamp, since my goal is this:

*To display **23-02-2018 09:47:13** as **23-02-2018 {atLabel} 09:47 {$hoursLabel}***. In other words this would look in an English version as follows:

**23-02-2018 09:47:13** as **23-02-2018 at 09:47 hours**

===============================================================

**CURRENT DISPLAY**:

[image]

^ This is achieved by the following Smarty code:

```
{foreach from=$ticketConversationList item=ticketConversation}
  <div class="holder" style="border-radius: 0;">
    <i class="pull-right">{$ticketHistoryPostedAt}{$ticketConversation.posted_at}</i>
  </div>
{/foreach}
```

*{$ticketHistoryPostedAt}* =
[image]

*{$ticketConversation.posted_at}* =
[image]
< - This gets fetched using a SQL query on the database, and then the array is send to the foreach using smarty->assign()

*NOTICE: This post is not a duplicate of a DATETIME into DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS because my question is specifically about splitting the TIMESTAMP as so I can enter in strings into the display.*

Comment: explode on the base of space.

Comment: Please refer below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14457250/php-splitting-the-date-and-time-within-a-timestamp-value-in-mysql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql: Setup the format of DATETIME to 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS' when creating a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338031/mysql-setup-the-format-of-datetime-to-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmmss-when-creating-a-tab)

Comment: Just format it when you retrieve it from the database. [Take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338031/mysql-setup-the-format-of-datetime-to-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmmss-when-creating-a-tab) and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explode on the base of space then put them together to display in the format you want to

```
$dateTime = $ticketConversation.posted_at;
$data = explode(" ", $dateTime);
echo $data[0] ." at ".$data[1]." hours";
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use something similar as this in template?

{$ticketConversation.posted_at|date_format:%d-%m-%Y}{atLabel}{$ticketConversation.posted_at|date_format:%H:%i}{$hoursLabel}

You might have to convert the retrieved date from DB to DateTime type object.